# Salesforce - Using jQuery to change (and update) on a standard layout

Tags: jquery, salesforce, apex-code

We have a colored rating field on our opportunity layout as a likelihood-of-success indicator. Right now it is driven by a picklist (also on the layout, right below it). See this screenshot for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jdHn.png

I'd rather be able to click the color and have it change as a result, and for this to stick.

Here's a stab at some jQuery proof-of-concept... it does work, and changes the color from green to red, for example. However the part I'm clueless about, is getting that to stick (i.e. getting the record to be updated).

In the code below, the image gets replaced for the user's benefit, and the picklist gets changed, in theory, for the system's.. but that's part I'm pretty sure is all jacked up:

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$('document').ready(function() {
  j$('#00NR0000001APo7_ileinner').click(function() {
    j$('#00NR0000001APo7_ileinner').replaceWith('<img src="/img/samples/color_red.gif" height="15" width="70" border="0">');
    j$('#00NR0000001AKPR_ileinner').replaceWith('Red')
  });
});
```

This script lives in an HTML homepage component, and I got the element id's via chrome. I'm just starting to learn jQuery, so A) is that sustainable way of doing it - or will they not be static? and B) is it possible for any client-side changes like this color shift to be saved?

Comment: The clinet-side environment does not use permanent storage; you'll have to put somethin on the server side to make the changed color stay.

Comment: Your users will likely have to click something (ie. "Save") to push the value back to the server; could you put this into the Edit page, or turn on in-line editing?  An alternative would be to hit the API using the AJAX toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

A) is that sustainable way of doing it - or will they not be static?

> Salesforce can change their page structure or naming conventions at
>   any time, so it's not a good idea to hard code ID's like this.  Having
>   said that, sometimes it is the only way to accomplish what you're trying to do in Salesforce (and something I have to do all the time)

B) is it possible for any client-side changes like this color shift to be saved?

> Cookies would be the way to go for a client side solution, but it
>   would be unique to the browser being used and subject to expiration /
>   cookie deletion.
>
> [Hraefn's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250641/salesforce-using-jquery-to-change-and-update-on-a-standard-layout#comment14865912_11250641) concerning the [AJAX toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index.htm) would be a
>   better place to start.  You would need a custom field or object to
>   save the change in Salesforce.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like what you want to do is save the status of the ui element status on the server. Look at saving the setting in MySQL or a text file, etc. You could then pass the MySQL variable to jQuery via PHP and use an if statement to change the colour depending on the value of the variable.

THe most you can do in jQuery alone is to set a cookie for the change to stick (until the cookie expires), but it'll only apply to the one machine the cookie has been set on.

Comment: He is working on salesforce platform. Php/Mysql doesn't exist there.